# Setting a default value for a config defined value?

Tags: xml, magento

How can I assign a default value to a config value, which i am defining in a system.xml file? Currently it defaults to 'no', but i want it to default to 'yes'.

Here is my current definition code:

```
<catalog>
            <groups>
                <my_val>
                    <label>My Label</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>160</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <my_inner_val translate='label comment'>
                            <label>Enable seperate cart items</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </my_inner_val>
                    </fields>
                </my_val>
            </groups>
        </catalog>
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config.php you can set those with

```
<default>
    <catalog>
        <my_val>
            <my_inner_val>###</my_inner_val>
        </...
```

I'm not entirely sure the value you'll need to place in for ###, either 1 or yes should probably work though.